# Exponential log file growth on quiet database with log backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log

I have a small (~3GB) database in Full recovery mode, with full backups at midnight and transaction log backups at noon.

Despite being a testing database with virtually no activity, the size of the log files (and transaction log backups) are growing exponentially:

| Date | Size |
| --- | --- |
| March 2: | 200MB |
| March 3: | 560MB |
| March 4: | 963MB |
| March 5: | 1.5GB |
| March 6: | 2.5GB |
| March 7: | 5.9GB |

For comparison, the nigh-identical production version of the same database has transaction log backups (same schedule) under 100MB.

The autogrow is set to 10%, so each new VLF winds up 10% larger than the last, but it's a mystery to me why new VLFs are created several times a day at all!  There are no open transactions, and when I checked DBCC LOGINFO last night, there were numerous large VLFs with status 0, so log backup is truncating fine.  They were all status 2 this morning.

Doing periodic LOGINFO & LOGSPACE checks this morning, I saw the log expand to add a VLF, despite having virtually nothing in the last one:

[image: loginfo increase]

The previous size would have been ~6369MB, so that VLF had about 25/700MB in use.

Can something cause SQL Server to move onto a new VLF before the active one is remotely full?

EDIT:

Trace shows a 90 minute shrink and grow cycle

| Action | duration | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Log File Auto Grow | 1473000 | 2021-03-08 10:50:14.970 | 2021-03-08 10:50:16.443 |
| Log File Auto Shrink | 1000 | 2021-03-08 10:50:13.763 | 2021-03-08 10:50:13.763 |
| Log File Auto Grow | 1116000 | 2021-03-08 09:19:36.813 | 2021-03-08 09:19:37.930 |
| Log File Auto Shrink | 1000 | 2021-03-08 09:19:35.827 | 2021-03-08 09:19:35.827 |
| Log File Auto Grow | 1090000 | 2021-03-08 06:48:33.760 | 2021-03-08 06:48:34.850 |
| Log File Auto Shrink | 1000 | 2021-03-08 06:48:32.207 | 2021-03-08 06:48:32.207 |
| Log File Auto Shrink | 1000 | 2021-03-08 05:17:54.147 | 2021-03-08 05:17:54.147 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the error log ?
Run select * from sys.databases & look at the log_reuse_wait_desc column.
Run DBCC OPENTRAN and see if you have any open active transactions ?

Query the default trace and get the timings of when the file growths are happening
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3445/using-the-sql-server-default-trace-to-audit-events/

Comment: log_reuse_wait_desc is LOG_BACKUP, which makes sense since all VLFs are full, and it's on full recovery mode.  DBCC OPENTRAN shows nothing

Comment: Are your transaction log backups succeeding ? Maybe time to run them more than once a day ?

Comment: They all succeed.  Theres no reason to run them more frequently, because there's no activity, and they don't stop the exponential growth.  The log hit 25GB last week before I shrank it.

Comment: & what is in the SQL Server error log & the windows event logs ?
Most common cause of log growth is an index rebuild job so worth double checking for that but right now that seems like a long shot. 

Try querying the default trace to see what time the file growths are happening & see if you can get a correlation

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3445/using-the-sql-server-default-trace-to-audit-events/

Comment: Nothing in the SQL error log and the windows event log only has an occasional DNS blip.  The maintenance routine only has a reorganize, not a rebuild.  I'll have to look into the trace.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the trace!  It's happening every 90 minutes, and more importantly, immediately _after_ an auto shrink (see above).  Now to figure out why it has an auto shrink every 90 minutes.

Comment: Is your question answered now ?